# Extended ASCII characters such as euro symbol being converted to its unicode equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, string, ms-access, character-encoding

I have the euro symbol stored in an MS-Access database table:

```
SELECT
CurrencySymbol,
Len(CurrencySymbol) AS DataLength,
Asc(CurrencySymbol) AS AsciiCode
FROM table1;

CurrencySymbol DataLength AsciiCode
-------------- ---------- ---------
€              1          128
```

And here is the .NET code I am using to read this table:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + args[0]);
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [table1]", connection);
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    for (i = 0, j = reader.FieldCount; i < j; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(reader.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

Originally, I was writing the data to a text file using `StreamWriter`. I noticed that the euro symbol was written as `â‚¬` which probably is the *unicode* euro symbol encoded in UTF-8. Debugger results:

```
reader.GetValue(i).ToString()                  -> "€"
reader.GetValue(i).ToString().ToCharArray()[0] -> 8364 '€'
```

How can I enforce .NET to <del>spit out</del> output the extended ASCII characters as-is? The characters are supposed to be written in a CSV file.

Comment: The characters need to go in a text file -- an ANSI text file.

Comment: (this is in relation to a now-deleted comment claiming that the euro symbol is not covered by any ANSI encodings): the euro symbol is in code-page 1252 (Western European) with value 128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that these two lines:

```
reader.GetValue(i).ToString()                  -> "€"
reader.GetValue(i).ToString().ToCharArray()[0] -> 8364 '€'
```

do what you want tells me we can stop looking at data-access and MS Access, 'cos that is all working fine. The problem is simply: writing that to a file. The trick, then, is to be explicit when you create the `StreamWriter`. If you look at the `StreamWriter` constructors, you'll see that some take an `Encoding`. If you leave it blank, **it will default to UTF-8**. So: don't leave it blank. Explicitly pass in your chosen `Encoding`. I would recommend you figure out **exactly** which code-page you mean, and use:

```
const int CodePage = ....; // TODO: only you know this
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(CodePage);
using(var file = File.Create(path))
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(file, enc)) {
   ... // write the contents
}
```

You could also use `Encoding.Default` (the system's default ANSI code-page), but that is a bit hit and miss.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get the example code to work, I tried: `System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); StreamWriter dataFile = new StreamWriter(dataFilePath, enc);`: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.StreamWriter.StreamWriter(string, bool)' has some invalid

Comment: @Salaman look again: I have *two* `using` - one opens the `FileStream` (binary, no concept of encoding) - one binds to the `Stream` with a particular encoding. I don't pass a path to `StreamWriter` - I pass a `Stream`